# How to open a document in a dynamiccontent control facet from a viewpanel control

Tags: xpages

I have a `dynamiccontent` control on a XPage with a facet containing a custom control which has a `viewpanel` in it. I also have a second facet in the `dynamiccontent` control containing a custom control which is connected to a document data source.

What I am trying to figure out is when the `viewpanel` custom control is loaded in the `dynamiccontent` how do I get the links in the `viewpanel` custom control to load the `dynamiccontent` facet containing the custom control connected to the document data source and display the document?

Comment: I think the Dynamic Content example in the Extension Library Demo database is self explaining. It use also a view and a document

Comment: @FrankvanderLinden - you are correct. The answer is in the Extension Library Demo database. I should have looked there first!

Comment: shall I make it an answer, so you mark it as answered?

Comment: @FrankvanderLinden yes, please do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the Dynamic Content example in the Extension Library Demo database is self explaining. It use also a view and a document

Answer (score 0):

Well I'ver always found ViewPanels to be very limiting if you want to do anything fancy.  I don't think you can easily use any of the built in features.  I would personally use a Repeat Control and then have a button that takes the intended document and gets the unid.  You can then put that unid into a viewScope variable, change your dynamic content control to the document facet and have that custom control get the unid from viewScope to get the correct document.

I long time ago I did a rather crappy demo that showed a couple of these techniques.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSLAy6U2_3A
The CSS attempt failed there but you should be able to see a repeat control and putting the unid into scope etc.  It might help you a little.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion - the extension library example database shows how to do this using an eventhandler on the viewcolumn.